# Best method if changes not committed in SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have the following:
Eclipse IDE and SVN
b = branch
t = time

```
t0   b1
t1   b1 -> b2 b2 branched from b1
t2         b2 Mod fileZ       
t3   b1 Mod fileZ Add fileX
t4   b1 checked-in
```

Branch 1 will never need what is in Branch 2.
How would one incorporate fileZ into b2 as b2 is not yet checked-in yet modified same file?
Hope this is clear, trying to minimize merging conflicts. FileX not an issue as no conflicts.

Comment: Tried to create a patch from b2 and then apply it to b1?

Answer (score 0):

- Checkout HEAD of b2
- Merge b1/fileZ into it
- Commit